# Get last path from URL

Tags: c#, winforms, url

I have Url in my c# app, for example: `https://www.instagram.com/testtesttest/`

And I want to get the last path component from it: `testtesttest`

I'm using this code:

```
public static String GetUserNameInstagramUrl(String url)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
    return uri.Segments.Last();;
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the last path with `/` in the end.
There is any method to get the last path without removing the `/` by myself?

Comment: `url.Trim('/')` ?

Comment: @David I'm want something more generic that will be dynamic for more kind of String.

Comment: change the last line to this:

return uri.Segments.Last().Trim('/');

Comment: No, if what you need is not provided by the API then you have some work to do.

Comment: When you look for more generic way, it probably means you want to handle some other input cases as well. Can you please share some other inputs and expected outputs? For example what would be the output for the following inputs `https://example.com`, `https://example.com/a`, `https://example.com/a/`, `https://example.com/a/b`, `https://example.com/a/b/c.d`? Also the uri may have query string. What would be the expected result in previous cases if there is query string in the uri?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do TrimEnd at the end

```
public static String GetUserNameInstagramUrl(String url)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
    return uri.Segments.Last().TrimEnd('/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to go with trimming the '/' at the end

```
public static string GetUserNameInstagramUrl(string url)
            {
                Uri uri = new Uri(url);            
                return uri.Segments.Last().TrimEnd('/');
            }
```

Comment: How is it different from the other answer?